# How to define a display width of numeric variables when exporting an R data frame to SPSS?

Tags: r, csv, format, export, spss

How to set a custom data width for numeric values exported from an R's data frame to an SPSS file? Regardless of the numeric precision in the data, after exporting the frame to SPSS, the data gets displayed as F8.2 (which is default for the numeric data type). In SPSS itself it's easy to reformat the width with `FORMATS` command, but I need to set accurate values beforehand, on exporting the file from R.

It's a part of the following scenario: read a CSV file into R, set variable and value labels, define missing values, define numeric data display widths, then save the data as an SPSS file.

Interestingly, some R packages like `haven`, `tidymetadata`, or `codebook` can strip SPSS attributes away from data frames read from SPSS, so I'm wondering if there is a way to set the attributes as well.